# Not displaying star rating on production (heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, raty

I'm using the gem ratyrate, and locally it works fine, but in production it generates a 404 error of the images.

Some solutions I found were these, but they do not work

/initializer/raty_helper.rb
https://github.com/wazery/ratyrate/blob/master/lib/ratyrate/helpers.rb

raty.js.rb

```
$.fn.raty.defaults.half = false;
$.fn.raty.defaults.halfShow = true;
$.fn.raty.defaults.path = '<%= asset_path('images') %>';
$.fn.raty.defaults.cancel = false;

$(function(){
  $(".star").each(function() {
    var $readonly = ($(this).attr('data-readonly') == 'true');
    var $half     = ($(this).attr('data-enable-half') == 'true');
    var $halfShow = ($(this).attr('data-half-show') == 'true');
    var $single   = ($(this).attr('data-single') == 'true');
    $(this).raty({
      score: function() {
        return $(this).attr('data-rating')
      },
      number: function() {
        return $(this).attr('data-star-count')
      },
      half:        $half,
      halfShow:    $halfShow,
      single:      $single,
      path:        $(this).attr('data-star-path'),
      starOn:      '/star-on.png',
      starOff:     '/star-off.png',
      starHalf:    '/star-half.png',
      cancel:      $(this).attr('data-cancel'),
      cancelPlace: $(this).attr('data-cancel-place'),
      cancelHint:  $(this).attr('data-cancel-hint'),
      cancelOn:    '/cancel-on.png',
      cancelOff:   '/cancel-off',
      noRatedMsg:  $(this).attr('data-no-rated-message'),
      round:       $(this).attr('data-round'),
      space:       $(this).attr('data-space'),
      target:      $(this).attr('data-target'),
      targetText:  $(this).attr('data-target-text'),
      targetType:  $(this).attr('data-target-type'),
      targetFormat: $(this).attr('data-target-format'),
      targetScoret: $(this).attr('data-target-score'),
      readOnly: $readonly,
      click: function(score, evt) {
        var _this = this;
        if (score == null) { score = 0; }
        $.post('<%= Rails.application.class.routes.url_helpers.rate_path %>',
        {
          score: score,
          dimension: $(this).attr('data-dimension'),
          id: $(this).attr('data-id'),
          klass: $(this).attr('data-classname')
        },
        function(data) {
          if(data) {
            // success code goes here ...

            if ($(_this).attr('data-disable-after-rate') == 'true') {
              $(_this).raty('set', { readOnly: true, score: score });
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: could you post some logs?

Comment: @bangbang  GET domain.com/assets/star-off.png 404 (Not Found) star-off.png

Answer (score 1):

Add to your your `config/environments/production.rb`:

`config.serve_static_assets = true`

Comment: Could you try and spin up your development server on production mode?

Comment: I solved this by doing this
rails assets: precompile

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to execute this command:

```
rails assets:precompile
```

Comment: being tied to this will mean you'd have to run this every time your assets change or you'd end with a stale version. This seems rather temporary